# lstlisting environment it not treated as verbatim, which results in several false positives

Tags: filetype-tex, error, plugin-ale

ALE does not treat text inside of listing environments like verbatim, which spawns many whitespace related errors (i.e. space before punctuation marks, etc.).

I've found somewhat of an answer on StackExchange [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285301/ignore-errors-in-environments-in-latex-suite-in-vim), however this seems to be outdated, and does not work.

After a bit of researching I've found that in order to solve this I simply need to add listings to append the texzone variable, which will make vim ignore all errors within the confines of the listing.

I'd like to know how I can accomplish this, or how to solve the problem in general.

I believe that [this piece of code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/tex.vim#L639) is concerned.

here's a screenshot:
[image: capture]
the problem is the "whitespace before punctuation marks" errors.

To reproduce simply insert any `lstlisting` with space before punctuation marks, e.g. `if(a != 0)`, there is a space before the exclamation point.

Comment: I suppose if we would have more information about the symptoms (e.g. screen shots) and about how to reproduce your problem it would help us to help you.

Comment: If we knew what compiler/linter produced that warnings, it might be possible to suggest a solution. But I don't think this is necessarily an ALE or Vim issue: the program that produces the warnings should not look in `lstlisting` environments.